# Create list of lists for specific columns of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, rows

Having this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,8],[33,44,55,9],[555,556,222,10]])
df.columns = ['Al', 'Bandy', 'George', 'Zulu']
```

I get this:

[image]

I need a list of lists **only** from columns **Bandy** and **George**, that results exactly like this:

```
[[2,3], [44,55],[556, 222]]
```

So far I have managed with the code below and the result is a reversed dataframe, but I am quite sure there should be a better way than reversing it back:

```
pd.DataFrame(list([df['Bandy'], df['George']]))
```

Comment: You can use: `df[['Bandy','George']].to_numpy().tolist()` which converts the values to array and then a list

Comment: @anky_91 - yup, it works. Consider adding it as an  anwer :)

Comment: No problem . However this question has been asked before hence I closed as duplicate :)